# Как управлять доступом к компонентам приложения?

Tags: архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, best-practice

Есть приложение, состоящее из большого числа модулей (компонентов). Каждый модуль отвечает за какой-то функционал в приложении. Т.е. приложение представляет из себя ядро и набор этих самых подключаемых модулей. Появилась идея продавать каждый такой модуль в отдельности. В итоге получится ситуация, когда у разных заказчиков будут разные наборы из модулей.

У меня настроено автоматическое развертывание приложения и я не хочу думать какие модули мне нужно копировать, а какие нет. По-умолчанию копируются все модули, а приложение по какому-нибудь конфигу уже само будет решать какие компоненты активировать для данного заказчика, а какие нет.

Соответственно нужно иметь возможность при развертывании приложения на сервере заказчика где-то задать какие модули активируются у него, а какие нет. **Где и как организовать хранение такие настроек?**

Изначальная идея в виде конфига, где было бы нечто похожее на следующую xml, отпала сразу, т.к. любой админ у заказчика смог бы зайти в этот конфиг, легко допетрить для чего эти настройки и включить себе весь функционал, за который он не платил.

```
<modules>
    <module1>Enabled</module1>
    <module2>Enabled</module2>
    <module3>Disabled</module3>
    <module4>Enabled</module4>
    <module5>Disabled</module5>
</modules>
```

Далее была идея воспользоваться так называемой битовой маской или некоторые маскированием еще такой подход именуют. Т.е. в конфиге или в базе в таблице каждому модулю ставим в соответствие число, равное степеням двойки:

```
module1 = 1
module2 = 2
module3 = 4
module4 = 8
module5 = 16
```

Затем при развертывании также в конфиге или в базе заводим поле, в котором будет число, побитовое "И" которого с каждым модулем возвращает 1 (активировать модуль) или 0 (не активировать). Зададим такое число для примера из xml, где нужно было выключить 3 и 5 модули.

```
module1 = 01 в десятичной системе = 00001 в двоичной системе
module2 = 02 в десятичной системе = 00010 в двоичной системе
module3 = 04 в десятичной системе = 00100 в двоичной системе
module4 = 08 в десятичной системе = 01000 в двоичной системе
module5 = 16 в десятичной системе = 10000 в двоичной системе
-------------------------------------------------------------
value01 = 11 в десятичной системе = 01011 в двоичной системе
```

Как видно из примера, при развертывании у заказчика я буду задавать число 11. Побитовое "И" двоичной версии этого числа со всеми модулями вернет единицу только для 1,2 и 4 модулей, а для 3 и 5 вернет ноль и система скроет эти разделы. Довольно удобно, но есть "НО" - битовая маска тоже довольно известная тема. Более-менее толковый админ без труда допетрит какое число надо поставить, чтобы включить все модули.

Была идея все эти числа через какой-нибудь шифратор прогонять, чтобы в конфиге или базе были краказябли вместо цифр и человек не понял какие значения зашифрованы, а в приложении пропускать через дешифратор и работать. Проблему решает, но это сильно на костыль похоже, чем на качественное решение.

В общем, какие есть best practice на эту тему? Может какие-то другие варианты?

P.S. Про стандартную безопасность, которая юзается чуть ли не в каждом приложении, писать не нужно. Я про ту тему, когда есть таблица пользователей, таблица ролей, таблица пермишенов и т.п.

Comment: "У меня настроено автоматическое развертывание приложения и я не хочу думать какие модули мне нужно копировать, а какие нет." - вот в автоматизации конфиг и парсите, и получайте разные комплекты.

Comment: Кстати, уточните на каком ЯП/фреймворке у вас все. Ответы для JS или для C++ могут быть несколько разными.

Comment: Kromster, "конфиг и парсите"... По хорошему да, нужно не поставлять все компоненты, а поставлять только нужные каким-нибудь конфигом при развертывании, но это куда более трудоемкая задача, чем переложить эту функцию на клиент. Если ничего умнее придумать не сможем, то так и будем делать.

Comment: У меня обычный asp.net (не core), написано все на C#. Стиль решения проблеме не сильно зависит от используемых языков или технологий.

Comment: Все что вы поставите клиенту - автоматически становится взламываемо и доступно клиенту. (если взломать дешевле чем купить) Единственный вариант чего-то клиенту не разрешить - не отдавать клиенту этого вообще.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы поставляете заказчикам всё приложение целиком, со всеми модулями, то так или иначе сохраняется вероятность нелегитимного включения функционала. Никакими "шифраторами" такого шила не утаить. Лучше по-честному разделите вашу программу на основу + плагины. Каждая часть должна быть оформлена как отдельный пакет, чтобы их можно было свободно комбинировать. Конечно же, подробности зависят от используемых вами технологий, но есть некоторый общий подход, который позволяет упростить распространение клиент-серверных приложений.

Есть смысл изучить следующие системы пакетирования.

- [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) для [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs)
- [PEAR](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.commands.package.php) для [php](/questions/tagged/php)
- [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/LEONT/Module-Build-0.4224/lib/Module/Build.pm) для [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)
- [PyPI](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) для [python](/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: Да. Тоже думал, что лучше наверно будет еще на этапе развертывания определять конфигурацию, а не перекладывать это на клиент. Но это план Б. Просто сделать автоматическую сборку нужной конфигурации приложения на порядок трудозатратнее, чем поставлять все и позволить приложению решать что активировать. Если какого-то нормального решения для плана А не найду, то никуда не деться, буду допиливать функционал по развертыванию, чтобы он конфигурации поддерживал.